# Who are these Sesame Street characters?

Tags: sesame-street

[image]

My nephew has a book and is at the stage where he's pointing at the pictures, wanting to know what they are. *Sesame Street* isn't that big here in Australia, so I'm not familiar with all the charactes. Can anyone help to identify them?

From top left to right:

1. Elmo
2. Oscar the Grouch
3. Cookie Monster
4. Ernie?
5. Bert?
6. ???
7. ???
8. Big Bird
9. ???
10. Count von Count
11. ???
12. ???

Comment: ID questions are off-topic. This can be easily solved by looking at wikipedia.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Ah, sorry. I wasn't sure since the help article lists ```Identifying a movie or TV series``` as being off-topic, and I thought that wasn't what I was asking. Thanks for the heads up, will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order:

[Super Grover](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Grover)

[Zoe](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Zoe)

[Abby Cadabby](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Abby_Cadabby?so=search)

[Telly Monster](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Telly_Monster?so=search)

[Rosita](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Rosita?so=search)